# How to combine different IF and OR in the same excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a GP trying to build an excel sheet to adjust the insulin dose according to the glycemia levels.

For that I need to make a formula like this
IF(F8<=B15;D9+C15),OR,IF(F8<=B16;D9+C16),OR,IF(F8<=B17;D9+C17),OR,IF(F8<=B18;D9+C18),OR,IF(F8<=B19;D9+C19)

So it means that I have a glycemia level "F8" and if it is below B15, then the insulin dose should be D9 plus the "adjustment"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens when F8 > B19?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this is what you are looking for

=IF(F8<=B15,D9+C15,IF(F8<=B16,D9+C16,IF(F8<B17,D9+C17,IF(F8<B18,D9+C18,IF(F8<=B19,D9+C19,0)))))

I am assuming the value is 0 if F8 > B19.  Basically this is

```
IF F8<=B15
    result = D9+C15
ELSEIF F8<=B16
    result = D9+C16,
ELSEIF F8<B17
    result = D9+C17,
ELSEIF F8<B18
    result = D9+C18,
ELSEIF F8<=B19
    result = D9+C19
ELSE
    result = 0
```

which is hopefully what you are looking for

** Edit VBA Version **

If you are working in VBA, the formula doesn't have to be restricted to one line

```
Const levels = 4
Dim glycemia(levels) As Double
Dim insulin_adj(levels) As Double
Dim insulin_base As Double
Sub InsulinDoseInit()
    ' Initialize the data
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    insulin_base = sht.Cells(9, 4) ' D9
    For lvl = 0 To levels
        glycemia(lvl) = sht.Cells(15 + lvl, 2) 'b15 etc
        insulin_adj(lvl) = sht.Cells(15 + lvl, 3) 'c15 etc
    Next
End Sub
Function InsulinDose(glycemia_lvl As Double) As Double
    Dim dose As Double
    dose = 0
    For lvl = 0 To levels
       ' instead of using nested if, just loop through until
       ' the level is found, then set the dose and exit
       If glycemia_lvl <= glycemia(lvl) Then
           dose = insulin_base_level + insulin_adj(lvl)
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
    InsulinDose = dose
End Function
Sub TestFunction()
    InsulinDoseInit
    ' To see the result, Ctrl+G, look at the immediate window
    Debug.Print InsulinDose(7.8)
    Debug.Print InsulinDose(5#)  ' 5.0 as a double otherwise it is an integer
    Debug.Print InsulinDose(10.3)
    Debug.Print InsulinDose(12.9)
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But I have a newbie/dumb question. I tried to make it run under developer mode going to Visual Basic > tools > macros.... I put the code you posted but nothing happened.

Comment: This is a formula that you put in a cell.  I'll work out what the equivalent VBA routine is.